# What word is used to explain the omission from writing or words that are superfluous or can be understood from contexual clues

Tags: single-word-requests

The omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or can be understood from contextual clues

Comment: 'Deletions' is a hypernym, but these far too frequently lead to ambiguities.

Comment: There are a number of [different such rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22deletion+rules%22), each with its own specifications of what may be deleted and its own lists of special features  and prohibitions. The subject is quite complex

Answer (score 4):

[Ellipsis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) is the omission of a word or words from a clause as understood, redundant, or superfluous:

> Did you buy any chocolate milk? No, the store was out [*of chocolate milk*].
>
> When they were children, John learned French and his brother [*learned*] Spanish.
>
> Rachel ordered something for lunch but I don't know what [*she ordered*].
>
> Peter wants to fly to Mexico City, but his wife doesn't want to [*fly to Mexico City*].
>
> Peter wants to fly to Mexico City, but his wife doesn't [*want to fly to Mexico City*].

The only time ellipsis is mandatory is in comparisons:

> John is taller than I [*am tall*].

Rather than solve the daunting question of whether something that is never there ever was in the first place, many casual speakers analyze *than* as a preposition, so that John is taller than *me*.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a coincidence. [I just mentioned this in chat not too long ago.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=42482184#42482184) There are a few terms that could be used for this, but I think the word ellipsis is the one you probably want to use the most:

> In grammar, omission; a figure of syntax by which a part of a sentence or phrase is used for the whole, by the omission of one or more words, leaving the full form to be understood or completed by the reader or hearer: as, “the heroic virtues I admire,” for “the heroic virtues which I admire”; “prythee, peace,” for “I pray thee, hold thy peace.”[—The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia (C.D.C.)]

Wikipedia, which licenses its text under the CC-BY-S.A. 3.0 terms, describes a few types of ellipsis in its [Ellipsis_(linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ellipsis_(linguistics)&oldid=811081822) article. I think The most interesting and easy to understand form of ellipsis is this:

> Answer ellipsis […]
> Answer ellipsis involves question-answer pairs. The question focuses an unknown piece of information, often using an interrogative word (e.g. who, what, when, etc.). The corresponding answer provides the missing information and in so doing, the redundant information that appeared in the question is elided, e.g.:
>
> > Q: Who has been hiding the truth? 
> > A: Billy <sub>has been hiding the truth.</sub>
> >  Q: What have you been trying to accomplish? 
> > A: <sub>I have been trying to accomplish</sub> This darn crossword.
>
> The fragment answers in these two sentences are verb arguments (subject and object NPs). The fragment can also correspond to an adjunct, e.g.:
>
> > Q: When does the circus start?
> >  A: <sub>The circus starts</sub> Tomorrow.
> >  Q: Why has the campaign been so crazy?
> >  A: <sub>The campaign has been so crazy</sub> Due to the personalities.
>
> Answer ellipsis occurs in most if not all languages. It is a very frequent type of ellipsis that is omnipresent in everyday communication between speakers.

Part of why answer ellipsis interests me is that it explains why so many questions end in prepositions: The prepositional object is supposed to be the answer. You can read more about answer ellipsis in particular in [Fragments and Ellipsis](http://home.uchicago.edu/merchant/pubs/fragments.pdf) (P.D.F.) by Jason Merchant

You may recollect that these three successive periods (…) are also sometimes referred to as an ellipsis. The "ellipsis points" as the Chicago Manual of Style, 15th edition terms them, are named after the syntactical construct. I have noticed a great deal of people around here are using elision instead, but please try to avoid that in favor of greater specificity. Elision, being a noun for the act of [eliding](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/elide), is a construct of pronunciation, not syntax, and refers to the reduction of syllables, and perhaps most specifically just the vowel sounds.

Comment: Ellipsis was the answer I was looking for